# How to format data Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to retrieve data from database column and put them to

```
[{1442507641,1},{1442507642,2},{1442507643,3},{1442507644,4}...]
```

format as the plot format requires.

I'm trying to do this by :

```
@data = TableName.where(:id => requiredid)
  .map {|r| { r.received_date.to_i => r.value } }
```

but this returns format

```
data=[{1442507641=&gt;6}, {1442507641=&gt;7}, {1442507641=&gt;5}, {1442507641=&gt;6}, {1442507641=&gt;5}, {1442507695=&gt;9}, {1442507695=&gt;9}, {1442507695=&gt;7}, {1442507695=&gt;8}]
```

How can I make the bracket as plot requires and remove the strange =&gt ?

Comment: you don't required key values ? comma separated hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this ought to do what you're asking for:

```
parts = TableName.where(:id => requiredid).map do |r|
  sprintf("{%d,%d}", r.received_date, r.value)
end

@data = "[#{parts.join(",")}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's only for your options to manipulate your data:

```
@data = []
@data = User.where(:id => requiredid).map {|r| @data << "{#{r. received_date}, #{r.value}}"}
```

First you make `@data` as array. Than collect the string into array.